# Remove a string that start with <div class="xxx"> and with</div> from a column in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `op_description`, in this table a column called `description`.

I want to strip HTML code from that column that start with `<div class="xxx">` to the end

Comment: Example - "Test <html> <div class="XXX"> Test</div>" If you have this data in that column, the result would be "Test <html> </div>". Is my understanding correct?

Else, do you want to replace the value if it starts with "<div class="XXX">" to </div> ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below?

```
UPDATE op_description SET description=IF(POSITION('<div class='XXX'>' IN 
description)=0,description,CONCAT(LEFT(description,POSITION('<div 
class='XXX'>' IN description)),"</div>"));
```

Example:

Input:

```
Test <html> <div class="XXX"> Test</div>
```

Output:

```
Test <html> </div>
```

Comment: it worked.. but if i reused.. it delete the other part.. i dont want to delete

Comment: Can you please give me an example of input and output? That would be easy for me to understand your requirement.

Comment: <div>
    <div class="ui-box product-property-main">
    <div class="ui-box-title">Item specifics</div>
    <div class="ui-box-body">
 i want to delete this part to the end -> <div class="ui-box product-description-main" id="j-product-description">
        <div class="ui-box-title">Product Description</div>
        <div class="ui-box-body">
 <div class="description-content" data-role="description" data-spm="1000023">
            <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blab
    <div class="ui-box transaction-feedback-main" id="j-transaction-feedback" data-spm="xx">

</div>
</div>

Comment: delete this  <div class="ui-box product-description-main" id="j-product-description"> to the end...

Comment: ur script work.. but i dont want when i reuse it.. it delete everything left after first time

Comment: it worked!!! thank you.. but i have like ">" this character is left at the end.. do you know why check http://i67.tinypic.com/2ild16s.jpg

Comment: Please give me your input and update query to find out why you have > symbol at the left.

Comment: UPDATE oc_product_description SET description=IF(POSITION('<div class="ui-box product-description-main" id="j-product-description">' INdescription)=0,description,CONCAT(LEFT(description,POSITION('<div class="ui-box product-description-main" id="j-product-description">' IN description)),"</div>"))

Comment: You query is correct. The symbol might not be incorporated from your query. Please check your input or any other things around it.